No connection to the internet trough WLAN after the first time installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm a complete Linux newbie, having used mainly Microsoft Windows since I was born 28 years ago. So on the recommendation of the internet I decided to try Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on an Acer Swift 1 SF114-34- C420 which I no longer really need.
After I installed the OS and opened the application center at the very end of the installation wizard to potentially install new applications, the program showed me the following message in the productivity tab:
SnapException(kind: dns-failure, message: lookup api.snapcraft.io [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:35782->[::1]:53: read: connection refused)

All other tabs do not work either. The program does not seem to be connected to the Internet.
I am trying to establish my Internet connection via WLAN, without Ethernet. My WLAN network is shown as connected and no other problems appear in the WLAN settings.
I have tried to use Firefox again, but the Internet connection also fails and the standard message for “Page not found” is displayed.
As a complete beginner, what can I do to get my Internet connection without destroying my system?
I would appreciate a quick, detailed and precise answer.
Many thanks and best regards
Josh

Can you provide the output of journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f? [Edit] your question to include the information.
